# Who to set box border when change line and border override content

Tags: html, css

set top or bottem border only remove middel lines all border.

**HTML:**

```
`<div class="pop-new-left content-wrapper" style="background-color:#69b3e7">
    <h1 class="staff-vol-name">Mukesh Khatri</h1>
    <h2 class="staff-vol-occu"></h2>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <span class="staff-vol-nation">India India</span>
    <span class="staff-vol-country">, Resident in New Delhi West</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>`
```

**CSS:**

```
`.pop-new-left span {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
 }`
```

Showing in below image:

[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

**I hope solve your problem.**

> **You can change .pop-new-left span css**

**padding: 10px 0px;**
To
**padding: 0px 0px;**